# Throwing new run time exception issue

Tags: java, oop

can anyone help figure out how to implement throwing a new RunTimeException? I'm trying to add it where the comment HERE is, it's in the play() method up top, the return false would be removed as it wouldn't be needed when I'm throwing the exception. The error I'm getting is "RunTimeException cannot be resolved to a type". Thank you.

```
package BS;

public class Board {
    private char[][] board;
    private char currentPlayer;
    
    //Initializes the board
    public Board() {
        this.board = new char[7][6];
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
                this.board[i][j] = 'Y';
            }
        }
        this.currentPlayer = 'X';
    }
    
    public char currentPlayer() {
        return this.currentPlayer;
    }
    
    public boolean play(int column) {
        //Determines which position on the board is free
        if (column < 1 || column > 6) return false; //HERE
        int saveI = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            if (this.board[i][column-1] == 'Y') {
                saveI = i;
            }
        }
        //Changes the position to the current player
        if (this.board[saveI][column-1] == 'Y') {
            this.board[saveI][column-1] = this.currentPlayer;
            if (this.currentPlayer == 'X') {
                this.currentPlayer = 'O';
            } else {
                this.currentPlayer = 'X';
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean gameOver() {
        //Horizontal checks
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            for (int j=3; j<6; j++) {
                if (this.board[i][j-3]=='X' && this.board[i][j-2]=='X' && this.board[i][j-1]=='X' && this.board[i][j]=='X') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Vertical checks
        for (int i=3; i<7; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
                if (this.board[i-3][j]=='X' && this.board[i-2][j]=='X' && this.board[i-1][j]=='X' && this.board[i][j]=='X') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Diagonal Checks
        
        //Diagonal Top Left to Bottom Right check
        for (int i=3; i<7; i++) {
            for (int j=3; j<6; j++) {
                if (this.board[i-3][j-3]=='X' && this.board[i-2][j-2]=='X' && this.board[i-1][j-1]=='X' && this.board[i][j]=='X') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Diagonal Top Right to Bottom Left check
        for (int i=3; i>7; i++) {
            for (int j=2; j>0; j--) {
                if (this.board[i-3][j+3]=='X' && this.board[i-2][j+2]=='X' && this.board[i-1][j+1]=='X' && this.board[i][j]=='X') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Diagonal Bottom Left to Top Right check
        for (int i=3; i>0; i--) {
            for (int j=3; j<6; j++) {
                if (this.board[i+3][j-3]=='X' && this.board[i+2][j-2]=='X' && this.board[i+1][j-1]=='X' && this.board[i][j]=='X') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Diagonal Bottom Right to Top Left check
        for (int i=3; i>0; i--) {
            for (int j=2; j>0; j--) {
                if (this.board[i+3][j+3]=='X' && this.board[i+2][j+2]=='X' && this.board[i+1][j+1]=='X' && this.board[i][j]=='X') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; //All checks failed
    }

    public char winner() {
        if (this.currentPlayer == 'X') {
            return 'X';
        } else if (this.currentPlayer == 'O') {
            return 'O';
        }
        return ' ';
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
                System.out.print(this.board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return "";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board();
        board.play(1);
        board.play(1);
        board.play(1);
        System.out.println(board);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write something like:

```
throw new RuntimeException("the engines won't take it, Captain!");
```

You probably omitted the 'new'

Or perhaps misspelled ["RuntimeException"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)  (there is no capital T)

---

I concur with @maio290 that it is more appropriate to throw an IllegalArgumentException in this case.  IllegalArgumentException is a subclass of RuntimeException, so in that sense is 'transparent' to callers.

Comment: You should probably add that an `IllegalArgumentException` is a better approach than to use a generic `RuntimeException` ;)

Comment: Note that `throw new RuntimeException()` should be reserved for rethrowing checked exceptions to make them unchecked, and __not for this__! Instead, throw something appropriate. This smacks of wanting to write: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("column must be between 1 and 6")` (IAEx is unchecked).